# LocalDb as storage for WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf, localdb

I am planning the following and I am asking for advice / critics on the setup.

- We want to move our user management code to a WCF service so that our client apps retrieve user data through that WCF API only.
- The API (library) shall be using LocalDb for storage as default.
- The WCF service shall use the library and expose its functionality.

Is that a sensible approach? We want to keep the user storage close to the service, but does LocalDb run when we install the service running as NetworkService? We can go with LocalSystem but only if required, of course.

If running as a service, would another services (e.g. both running as LocalSystem) be able to access the LocalDb?

Considering deployment: If the API creates / connects the LocalDb, would any other restrictions apply to deployment of the WCF service via MSI other than ".Net 4.0.2 needed"?